# How do you get BitTorrent on Ubuntu?

Tags: bittorrent

I want to know if it is possible to get bittorrent for ubuntu.

If yes, please answer. I tried searching for this but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I searched for "ubuntu bittorrent" on Google and DuckDuckGo and this was the first link that came up on both:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BitTorrent. A bit out of date, but it answers your question and has lots of links to Bittorrent clients, including the original.

Comment: There are several torrent clients and servers in the ubuntu repositories

Comment: you can use the transmission app that comes with Ubuntu(mine is version 20.04) it works same as bit-torrent on windows

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a package `qbittorrent`

To install it run following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install qbittorrent
```

Now to run through Terminal just type : `qbittorrent` and it will start working.

Comment: and remember "add to favourites" so that you dont have to type everytime.

Answer (score 17):

In many versions of Ubuntu, Transmission is pre-installed. It works in the same way.